# For Each Item in ListBox1 do something then add item to listbox2 vb

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach, listboxitems

I made an app to convert certain numbers to other format
i.e

> - 1 = A
> - 2 = B
> - 3 = C
> - 4 = D
> - 5 = E
> - ETC

I have made that function with no problem and I have been using it for quite sometime, but now I would like to do things faster and in a batch.
So it's really difficult for me to copy from a text file to my Textbox1 then press button1 then copy textbox2 to other text file.

So I was thinking in loading the text file into a List Box then do a loop for each item in that list into a second list that I can export to another text file.

The importing and exporting I have it covered but where I'm stuck at is to make the loop.

Here's what I have please if you know a better way to do it let me know or tell me how to fix it this way.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Using FD As New OpenFileDialog()
        FD.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        If FD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(FD.FileName))
        End If
    End Using
End Sub


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Do
    Dim Item As String = ""
    For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items
        Item &= i
        TextBox1.Text = Item
        TextBox2.Text = MYFUNCTION(TextBox1.Text)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    Next
    Loop Until TextBox1.Text = "END"

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'TextBox2.Text = MeidHexToDec(TextBox1.Text)

    Using FD As New SaveFileDialog()
        FD.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        If FD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim FileContent As String = ""
            For Each i As String In ListBox2.Items
                FileContent &= i & vbCrLf
            Next
            IO.File.WriteAllText(FD.FileName, FileContent)
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

So my final aim is to do something like this:

TextFile1.txt

> - 1
> - 2
> - 5
> - 5
> - 1
> - 3
> - 2
> - END

then after the conversion output

TextFile2.txt

> - A
> - B
> - E
> - E
> - A
> - C
> - B

The text file size will vary sometimes it will have only 10 items sometimes will be 50... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the `Do` loop at all and you can simplify the rest of your loop logic, like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each i As String In ListBox1.Items
        ListBox2.Items.Add(MYFUNCTION(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

You do not need to look out for the `END` marker, because everything in the file was read into the `ListBox1.Items` collection, thus once you have looped through all of the string values in `ListBox1.Items`, then you are at the end of the file.

The `MYFUNCTION` logic returns the transformation from number to letter, thus just add the result of that function into `ListBox2.Items` and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function Letr(N As Int16) As String
    Letr = Chr(N + 64)
End Function
```