# Importing data from text file to two listboxes

Tags: vb.net

I already have seen question 
[For Each Item in ListBox1 do something then add item to listbox2 vb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19719158/3756836), 
what I'm trying to do is importing text file for two lists. If i have a text file like this:

> character:number
>   character1:number1
>   character2:nubmer2

I want the characters in the `listbox1.Items` and the numbers in the `listbox2.Items`.
I know how to import data to single list box:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way I can think of...

```
Dim vData = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")     ' Read the file into an array first

For Each vLine In vData                    ' Go through each line
    Dim vParts = vLine.Split({":"c})       ' Split the character from the number
    ListBox1.Items.Add(vParts(0))          ' Put the character in one list...
    ListBox2.Items.Add(vParts(1))          ' ... and the number in the other
Next
```

If you have trouble with this, let me know and I'll expand it (add `Imports System.IO` to the top of your file).

Comment: this how to import it im curious how to export it to file text char:num new line char1:num1

Comment: Pretty much the same in reverse.  Get your data from each list, concatenate it together to form the line, add each line to a list, then dump the list to the file using `File.WriteAllLines`.